# Is this permanent related complexity class known?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, counting-complexity

Given a $\{0,1\}$ matrix $M$ let $\mathcal C$ be the class that accepts if the number of distinct prime factors that divide permanent of $M$ is even and rejects if the number of distinct prime factors that divide permanent of $M$ is odd.

1. Is $\mathcal C$ contained in $PP$, $\oplus P$ or $MP$?
2. What is the position of $\mathcal C$ in the counting hierarchy?